# Unable to upload htaccess in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, no-www

I am a complete beginner in Codeigniter. I am facing 2 problems

1. I am unable to upload htaccess file
2. If I need to upload where should I upload

Comment: Please add more details for others to understand your problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to upload htaccess in the view section of codeigniter

But it doesn't allow me to upload the htaccess file. Do I need more any other access to upload htaccess

Comment: What FTP client is used for such an action?

Comment: @Tpojka if I understand your question correctly I am using cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Upload it to the root folder.
Also you might need to remove the index.php from the url, if so you have to follow [this link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html).

Answer (score 0):

iF you are begginer, Follow these steps as show in link... https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Make sure, First `mod_rewrite` on your serevr. And `.htaccess` file uploded in root of project. Enjoy codeigniter .